# An algebraic problem I failed to solve

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Pls help me with this question. This is a question which came in 2006 Olympiad. Here more than 1 possible options can be correct. I tried like that I assumed that $x = y = z = a =b = c$ but failed. More than one options are correct but I was not able to eliminate any.

Eliminate $x,y,z$ from the equation
$$
\frac{x^2(y+z)}{a^3}=\frac{y^2(z+x)}{b^3}=\frac{z^2(x+y)}{c^3}=\frac{xyz}{abc}=1
$$

Here are the options:

1. $a^3+b^3+c^3=abc$
2. $a^3+b^3+c^3+abc=0$
3. $a^3+b^3+c^3+abc=2abc$
4. $a^3+b^3+c^3+2abc=abc$

Comment: Please don't use pictures.

Comment: Please see [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). It is used here usually, and it's worth to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option $2$ and $4$ are possible. An elimination shows that we have a solution given by
$$
z=\frac{- cx(ab + c^2)}{b^3+c^3},\quad 
y=\frac{- bx(ac + b^2)}{b^3+c^3},
$$
and some real number $x$, and
$$
a^3+b^3+c^3+abc=0.
$$